# Difference betweens the balls Pokeball, Master ball, Great ball and Ultra Ball

Tags: pokemon-go

Can any one please explain the use and the difference betweens the balls Pokeball, Master ball, Great ball and Ultra Ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different balls with different catch rates. 
In order:
- Pokeball
- Greatball   (lvl 12+)
- Ultraball   (lvl 20+)
- Masterball (100% catch rate)

Comment: That i know the basic difference in case want an example for an specific CP

Comment: @rahul AFAIK, catch rate depends on more than just the CP of the pokemon. Not sure which ones though.

Comment: is related on the CP, the bonus (where your ball lands) per throw , .. if you want exact calculations i cant answer that

Comment: @rahul, I think you misunderstand. The balls don't catch Pokémon of different CP, they simply increase your chances. The exact calculations how that works is unknown to the public.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray i didn't misunderstood, i am asking for example with CP (pokemon of same cp with different balls catch ratio)

Comment: as @crowleyastray said, the exact calculations are not public

Comment: Ultra ball is lvl 20 not lvl 15